# scanf with a message gives a different question than without it

Tags: c, scanf

```
scanf("Enter: %d",&a);
```

stores different number than the input value why?

```
scanf("%d",&a)
```

stores different value than the former.
when inputting he number 12 the first statement stores the number 32764 and the next one stores 12

Comment: No way to know without a [mcve].

Comment: `scanf("Enter: %d", &a)` expects a `'E'`, then a `'n'`, then a `'t'`, ... and lastly an integer. It is not "a message", it is stuff for the user to type! For message do `printf("Enter: "); fflush(stdout); if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: What do you expect from the 1st example ? and please check the return value of scanf  as it would indicate how many values were successfully parsed, otherwise `a` would have the same value as before if parsing was not possible.

Comment: @pmg It is not "stuff for the user to type".  It is the expected data to be read from stdin!  Do not conflate stdin with data entered from a keyboard.  Far too many novices will fail to note the distinction and will be confused for years.

Comment: Noted @WilliamPursell, I agree... was trying to simplify and ended up over-simplifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `scanf()` just tries to accept the format given by the programmer and try to assign them into the variable given in the next argument. It won't work for you like `printf()` to print something and then ask an input from the user.

The syntax:

```
scanf("Enter: %d", &a);
```

**Won't appear something like:**

```
Enter: // and wait...
```

It'll wait to input `Enter:` to read for `a`.

```
int a;
scanf("Enter: %d", &a);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

You must type in the input (case-sensitive):

```
Enter:120
```

to assign `120` to `a`.

to match the format given, otherwise, it'll return `0` and not `1` (the number of total variable(s) successfully assigned).

To achieve what you actually want to, use `printf()` or `puts()` to display the text to enter an input:

```
puts("Enter: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
scanf("Enter: %d",&a);
```

you should enter anything before `%d` for this case: `"Enter: "`, then enter the number.

`scanf()` skips `"Enter: "`, then accepts the number.